# How do I generate a bitmap from a model using using XNA?

Tags: performance, model, bitmap, xna

I wish to dynamically create an image (as a Texture2D) from a camera view of a 3D model using XNA-4.0.  I can set up a model and camera to get the view I desire, but because I will need to concurrently do this for many large and complicated models every frame, for best performance I think it will be substantially less computationally expensive if I can instead somehow draw or write that view to a bitmap once and then repeatedly blit it to the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use RenderTarget to put viewport contents into a texture. Create it, bind it before you draw, then unbind and call GetTexture. They are pretty fast and can be used even simultaneously (MRT - Multiple Render Targets, afaik). For example, I use four render targets to feed my data into my deferred rendering pipeline.

Comment: I think that the render target is what I need to use.  You don't happen to have a simple example of its use, do you?

Answer (score 0):

This technique is known as Imposters.

Here is a link for DirectX 9, shouldn't be too hard to adapt to XNA.

[Gamasutra Article](http://www.gamasutra.com/view/feature/130911/dynamic_2d_imposters_a_simple_.php)

Comment: This was a great article, and it covers exactly what I'm attempting to accomplish, but besides being about DirectX, it doesn't actually provide any code samples (all the links to code are broken).  Nice overview though.

Answer (score 0):

For anybody else looking for a simple example :-

```
int _newTextureWidth = 800;
int _newTextureHeight = 450;

Texture2D _newTexture = new Texture2D(GraphicsDevice, _newTextureWidth, _newTextureHeight);
RenderTarget2D _target = new RenderTarget2D(GraphicsDevice, _newTextureWidth, _newTextureHeight);

// Point the GraphicsDevice to your new RenderTarget so that all Draw calls output here.
GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(_target);
GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.Transparent);

// Do DrawModel and any other Draw calls here

// Reset the GraphicsDevice to ouput to the Screen again;
GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(null); 

//Finally simply cast to your new Texture2D
_newTexture = (Texture2D)_target;
```